# Rejecting start request for application appname because stop request is running for the application weblogic

Tags: deployment, weblogic

Rejecting start request for application appname because stop request is running for the application.

I have this exception when I starting an application. However, the application I've already deleted with force. Now I cannot start the new version app. and the old one is deleted.

For this problem, I would like to know how to cancel/delete the stop request for the application that I can start the new one.

Comment: are you using Admin Console to issue these start/stop requests?

Answer (score 3):

I had to restart the admin server